# How to get guild member's server icon in discord.js 13?

Tags: discord.js

How to get member's server icon in discord.js 13 and how do i change bot's server icon as guild.setIcon() didn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

To get the icon `guild.iconURL({ dynamic: true })`, if the guild have an animated icon, `dynamic` property will return a gif.
For set the icon use `guild.setIcon("./icon.png")`

EDIT:
Sorry, use `member.displayAvatarURL()`, this will return the avatar the member has on the guild, if the member doesn't have guild avatar it will return the avatar of the user (`user.displayAvatarURL()`), dynamic is always valid.
You can't change the bot's avatar on the guild

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i didn't ask for changing/getting guilds icon but guild member's icons and settings bot's icon

Comment: I edited the message